# Python equivalent of MATLAB's qfuncinv()

Tags: python, signal-processing

I am working on a few signal processing concepts. And I prefer to use Python over MATLAB.

I require the complementary CDF of the Gaussian to model my system.
I was able to write MATLAB's [`qfunc()`](http://mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/qfunc.html) as:

```
from scipy import special as sp

def qfunc(arg):
    return 0.5-0.5*sp.erf(arg/1.414)
```

However, how would I write a similar function for [`qfuncinv()`](http://mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/qfunc.html)?

Comment: [`erfinv`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.special.erfinv.html)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at scipy's stats.norm [module](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html), there is a ppf (percent point function) method that's the inverse of the CDF, seems to be just what you need